# Strip "http://" from pasted text into textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Javascript/jQuery so hopefully you can help me.

I have a textbox where most people are gonna paste links into. Is there a nice way for the textbox to detect that a link has been pasted (starts with `http://`) and then remove the protocol dynamically in the textbox without having to push a button or so afterwards?

Comment: Do you want it to strip out the "http://" immediately as soon as it's typed/pasted or just upon submission of a form?

Comment: What happens if somebody pastes a `https` link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want it stripped out as soon as the user types/pastes it:

Lets say for arguments sake that you've given the text input the id "url":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var timer;

  $("#url").live("keyup",function(){
       clearTimeout(timer);

       timer = setTimeout(function(){
           var textbox = $("#url");
           if (textbox.val().indexOf("https://") == 0)
               textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(8));
           if (textbox.val().indexOf("http://") == 0)
               textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(7));
       },500);
   });
});​
```

As mentioned by @Marcel Korpel in the comments this should now take care of what you want.

Comment: You could also do this `onkeypress` in combination with a timer (of (e.g.) one second, so one second after the last key is pressed the form field changes). And yes, I've seen URLs with `http://` in the middle of it, when using a site as some kind of proxy (to access sites from another IP address that has a subscription; e.g.: `https://www.example.com/access/http://hiddensite.org`).

Comment: @Marcel: please see my revised post above and let me know if that works. I set the delay to be only half a second as opposed to a full second but that is easily changed.

Comment: this [works](http://jsbin.com/ihopu/edit#preview), though I'm not sure if this works for the OP's actual problem ;), as it strips the protocol regardless of the fact it's `http:` or `https:`, making several sites inaccessible (when reattaching `http:` in the output).

Comment: With some slight modifications this worked very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.replace()`, basic JavaScript really, it actually accepts a regex so `string.replace(/^http:\/\//,"")` should suffice.

Comment: Added the regex version, this should do as thought.

Answer (score 2):

This will check to make sure that it starts with http:// and then replaces that.

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
       $("#url").change(
           function()
           {
               var textbox = $(this);
               if (textbox.val().indexOf("http://") == 0)
                   textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(7));
           });
    });​
```

Here is also a working example to check out:
http://jsfiddle.net/epwDA/4/

Comment: Thanks! Not quite as good as Ryan's solution but this also worked as a charm. Will mark this answer as useful when I can (apparently im too new to this site to do that yet..)

And thanks for the tip about jfiddle